# Absent method calls in Instruments stack trace

Tags: memory-leaks, xcode6, instruments

I'm trying to profile my app for memory allocations on a device using Instruments. The problem is the profiler shows only native method calls in the stack trace; my own methods don't show up, which makes the stack trace totally useless.

[image: Instruments Screen Shot]

I'm using XCode 6.4 and the device is an iPhone 5c running iOS 8.4.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was due to a .dSYMM file generated by XCode as part of the build. The file is used in debug mode to symbolicate method calls. Instruments doesn't seem to be aware of its location. In order to fix that I had to do the following:

- Before starting to record under instruments, go to File->Symbols
- Unfold your app item and select your app name
- Click "Locate" in front of dSYM path
- the dSYM file corresponding to the app should be under ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/[APP_NAME].app.dSYM.
- A dialog should pop up asking you whether Instruments should always look for dSYM files under that location; that's what you want
- Start recording; your method calls should now display properly

Comment: Doing this, I got a pop up with title "No new libraries to symbolicate" and body "The specified path didn't locate a dSYM for any of the selected libraries.".  Sorry for grave digging, but if you've got any other advice I'd love to hear!

Comment: Oh, the other answer actually seems to have done the trick for me. The only other thing I did was change the target of my app to match that of the device I was using. That didn't work itself, but I did it before trying this step, so perhaps since the original derived data was from the old target, it couldn't get the symbols right, but changing the target + clearing derived data worked?

Answer (score 0):

In Instrument 8.2.1  deleting the folders in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData seems to do the trick.

Comment: This did the trick for me. The only other thing I did was change the target of my app to match that of the device I was using. That didn't work itself, but I did it before trying this step, so perhaps since the original derived data was from the old target, it couldn't get the symbols right, but changing the target + clearing derived data worked?